# The term 'Get-MessageTrackingLog' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm using powershell, I just use `Get-MessageTrackingLog` after `login/Authentication`

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri “https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/” -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection/ .
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Get-MessageTrackingLog not recognized as the name of a  cmdlet

I want to search all emails in a mail box.

Comment: You should share more of your script I think, and when looking on online documentation, I found that this command only applies to:
Exchange Server 2010, Exchange Server 2013, Exchange Server 2016, Exchange Server 2019 - This cmdlet is available only in on-premises Exchange. Are you in one of this cases?

Comment: @Mikitori I am using Office 365, I don't know how to set on-premises.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the Powershell environment does not have definition for function and yet cmdlet `Get-MessageTrackingLog` is not recognized.

Cmdlet **Get-MessageTrackingLog** is part of **exchange** Powershell module.

In order to use any function from this module you would need to **install** and then **load it**.